# jquery datepicker positioning at scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I have put a jquery date picker in my project which come pops up when I click on the calender icon. the problem i have is when i click on the icon first the icon comes on the correct place(image 1), but when I scroll a little and click, it goes down a bit out of position(image 2) and if i scroll again and click, it goes down further(image 3).

image 1
[image]

image 2
[image]

image 3
[image]

following is my coding

```
 }
&-datepicker {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    *,
    >* {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
    &-calendar {

        border-color: $border-color;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: $border-width;
        th {
            background-color: $primary-theme-color;
        }
    }
    td {
        padding: 0rem;
    }
}
```

can somebody help me to fix the calender position and get it fix to the first place it opens up, no matter how far you scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Try     position: fixed; 
instead of     position: absolute;

Comment: Any more suggestion!!

Comment: I would try to keep position: fixed; for parent element also. Please visit this link might be helpful. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/    or https://teckstack.com/understand-css-positions